# JavaScript Eval function with functions and run them

Tags: javascript, eval

I got run into problem, i am making for three.js in-game editor and i have problems with executing function, but no problems with script executing.

I have tried doing

```
var codeEnv = function(){}
```

but it does not matter as it returns always

> Uncaught ReferenceError: codeEnv is not defined

My current main javascript code as below:

```
var env;

function init(){
    initCode();
}

function loadFile() {
    reader.open('get', 'code.txt', true); 
    reader.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(reader.readyState == 4) {
            editor.innerHTML = reader.responseText;
        }   
    };
    reader.send(null);
}

function replaceAll(find, replace, str) {
    return str.replace(new RegExp(find, 'g'), replace);
}

function initCode(){
    loadFile();
}

var textcode;

function startCode(){
    runCode = false;
    textcode = editor.innerHTML;
    textcode = replaceAll("&lt;", "<", textcode); //replace &lt; with <

    eval(textcode);

    env = codeEnv();

    env.initVars();
    env.init();

    runCode = true;
}

function render(){ // CONSTANTLY CALLED

    if(runCode){
        env.render();
    }

}
```

And my code.txt:

```
function codeEnv() {

    tihs.initVars = function() {
        var cubes = [];
        var rows, cols, spacing = 1.3 * 0.5;
        rows = cols = 5;

        for( var r = 0; r < rows; r++ ){
            cubes[r] = [];
        }
    }

    this.init = function() {
        for( var r = 0; r < rows; r++ ){
            for( var c = 0; c < cols; c++ ){
                var cube = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(0.5, 0.1, 0.5), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 'white'}));
                cube.position.set( r * spacing, 1, c * spacing);
                cubes[r][c] = cube;
                scene.add(cube);
            }
        }
    }

    this.render = function() {
        i += 0.05;
        for( var r = 0; r < rows; r++ ){
            for( var c = 0; c < cols; c++ ){
                var cube = cubes[r][c];
                cube.position.setY(Math.sin(r/rows + i) / 4 + Math.sin(c/cols + i) / 4 + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Editor is html textarea.

These codes just have needed information in them, everything related to problem.

Now it executes the code but initVars doesnt work?

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'initVars' of undefined

Thank you!

Comment: The code for converting the `txt` file to a JS function seems missing. `var` is not needed in front of `this`. You probably should revisit JS OO programming as calls like `codeEnv().render();` not really make sense (at least in your case).

Comment: Replaced the var in txt to function name(), but i dont understand what do you mean about the calls, shouldnt it work like my way?  Any examples? Thank you.

Comment: You corrections in the `txt` file are probably wrong: You want something like `this.initVars = function initVars() {`. I just hinted towards dropping the `var` you had in front. As for the call: You usually want to create one instance of you object, e.g. `var env = new codeEnv()` and then call that instance's methods like `env.initVars();`.

Comment: So you load the `code.txt` into an editor, that part I get. What I don't get is why you're calling `codeEnv()` within your main code. You haven't told the engine to actually *execute* the script contained in `code.txt` so it doesn't even know `codeEnv()` exists

Comment: Oh! Thank you! Why i havent seen that!

Comment: New Error, initVars doesnt want to work, error in main post.

Comment: Change `env = codeEnv();` to `env = new codeEnv();`. Anyhow, this is not the place for continuous debugging of your code. You can ask specific questions, but should do at least some of your debugging yourself.

Comment: Alright, gonna keep in mind. Thank you!